# How can I make an external button affect only one instance of a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am brand new to this, teaching myself, and could really use some guidance. I have a series of sliders that each have an info button. The info is revealed when the "info button" is pressed, and then hidden again when the "close button" is pressed. The problem is, I currently have to write new code for each slider using different class names (cover1, cover2, cover3, etc), because I don't know how to do this automatically.

Here's what the horrific code is currently doing:

```
$('.infobtn').click(function(){
    $('.cover', '.boxgrid').stop().animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:360});
    $(this).hide();
    $('.closebtn').show();
    $(".cover", '.boxgrid').css("pointer-events", "auto");
});
$('.closebtn').click(function(){
    $(".cover", '.boxgrid').stop().animate({top:'455px'},{queue:false,duration:360});
    $(this).hide();
    $('.infobtn').show();
    $(".cover", '.boxgrid').css("pointer-events", "none");
});


$('.infobtn2').click(function(){
    $(".cover2", '.boxgrid').stop().animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:360});
    $(this).hide();
    $('.closebtn2').show();
    $(".cover2", '.boxgrid').css("pointer-events", "auto");
});
$('.closebtn2').click(function(){
    $(".cover2", '.boxgrid').stop().animate({top:'455px'},{queue:false,duration:360});
    $(this).hide();
    $('.infobtn2').show();
    $(".cover2", '.boxgrid').css("pointer-events", "none");
});
```

etc.

Here's the HTML of one of the captions if that will help:

```
<div class="boxgrid captionfull" style="z-index: 51;">
    <div id="info" class="cover boxcaption">
        <div id="infotext">
            <h3>Sed eu rutrum velit. Nunc leo massa nunc. Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam laoreet, nibh
            vitae volutpat euismod, risus leo porta nunc, in hendrerit diam sem
            commodo orci. Cras vitae tincidunt sapien. Integer dolor nisl,
            egestas sit amet mollis a, viverra sed sem. Pellentesque rhoncus
            ursus justo, sit posuere.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="btn" class="infobtn">
    <img src="images/info.png" />
</div>

<div id="btn" class="closebtn" style="display: none;">
    <img src="images/close.png" />
</div>
```

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: You could give each button an extra attribute that matches the ID of the slider, and then pass that ID to the functions that reveal/close.

Comment: Firstly, don't use the same `ID` multiple times in a page, it ruins the point of using an `ID`. Secondly, you should just be able to give them all the same class name, look into jQuery's prev() function

Comment: not quite sure what you are trying to achieve maybe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/wsfdU/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice folks, I managed to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can make it simplier

```
function bind_events() {
  $('div.infobtn').each(function(index, ele) {
    $($(".cover", '.boxgrid')[index]).stop().animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:360});
    $(ele).hide();
    $($('.closebtn')[index]).show();
    $($(".cover2", '.boxgrid')[index]).css("pointer-events", "auto");
  });

  $('div.closebtn').each(function(index, ele) {
    $($(".cover", '.boxgrid')[index]).stop().animate({top:'455px'},{queue:false,duration:360});
    $(ele).hide();
    $($('.infobtn')[index]).show();
    $($(".cover", '.boxgrid')[index]).css("pointer-events", "none");
  });
}
```

This way you dont need to make more than one class for each type of element.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get this to work. By modifying [a code by AlexDuggleby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481065/jquery-show-hide-items-individually-with-same-class-name) I was able to get it working. Thanks for taking the time though! I'm sure it does work, and I just made errors trying to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm glad that you fixed your problem!

Comment: I want to show you how it came together, but can't fit it all in the comment box here. This will do, I guess: http://jsfiddle.net/APANZ/

Answer (score 0):

You can use event-binding function since you have pattern in class names.

```
function bind_events() {
  $('div[class^=infobtn]').each(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/)[0];
    if (num == null) num = '';

    $(".cover"+num, '.boxgrid').stop().animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:360});
    $(this).hide();
    $('.closebtn'+num).show();
    $(".cover2"+num, '.boxgrid').css("pointer-events", "auto");
  });

  $('div[class^=closebtn]').each(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/)[0];
    if (num == null) num = '';

    $(".cover"+num, '.boxgrid').stop().animate({top:'455px'},{queue:false,duration:360});
    $(this).hide();
    $('.infobtn'+num).show();
    $(".cover"+num, '.boxgrid').css("pointer-events", "none");
  });
}
```